# $R(T)$ and $N(T)$ are $T$-invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T:V\to V$ be linear. Show that $R(T)$ and $N(T)$ are $T$-invariant.

I know that $\dim(V)=\dim(N(T))+\dim(R(T))$, but I'm confused on where to go from here.

Comment: Do you know what "$T$-invariant" means?

Comment: Think about how $T$-invariant, $R(T)$, and $N(T)$ are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ T(N(T))=\{ 0\}\subset N(T)$$ and $$T(R(T))\subset T(V)=R(T)$$

Comment: This makes sense. I believe I was overthinking what T-invariant meant.

Answer (score 2):

This is mostly a matter of stating definitions.  Let's go through the proof that $R(T)$ is $T$-invariant, for example:

Suppose that $y \in R(T)$.  By definition, this means that there is a vector $x$ such that $y = Tx$.  We note that, by this very definition, $Ty \in R(T)$.

Since $Ty \in R(T)$ for every $y \in R(T)$, we conclude that $R(T)$ is a $T$-invariant subspace